# Windows 10 will not boot after Ubuntu installation on MacBook Air

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, macbook, boot-repair, grub-efi

Sick of macOS therefore I wanted to install dual boot of 
Win 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on a MacBook Air mid 2013 model.

1. Windows is installed and configured to boot via UEFI.
2. Ubuntu is installed and configured to boot via UEFI.
3. And I am currently seeing the grub menu at boot,
   however I cannnot boot into windows 10. Ubuntu works fine.

I have tried the boot-repair with no luck.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rjH3VwVtYN/)  is alo the Ubuntu Pastebin. I can also provide more information if needed.

Comment: Also forgot to mention that I have disabled system integrity protection on this Macbook